# As a Moroccan citizen travelling from Budapest to Morocco with a layover in UK for 8 hours do I need a visa to transit?

Tags: uk, transit-visas, ukrainian-citizens, stn, moroccan-citizens

I am a Moroccan citizen travelling from Budapest to Morocco with a layover of eight hours at London Stansted Airport. I only have cabin baggage and have a Ukrainian passport (mentioned in case it helps in something :) )

Do I need a visa to transit?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a [non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content](/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Since you arrive internationally [you have to enter UK](http://www.stanstedairport.com/at-the-airport/airport-transfers/), even if checking in again immediately after. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Moroccan_citizens) Morrocan citizens need a visa. The same holds [for citizens of Ukraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Ukrainian_citizens).

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
I m travelling with Rayair , I checked on an official website , and it sais I don't need a visa since won't pass through UK Border Control !
 I am just not sure where they are :( 
Soo confused !

Comment: Can you post the link to the site you refer to?

Comment: Sure ! Here is it , https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa 
I just wrote them an official email to ask about my case. hopefully they will reply . It seems each airport has its own policies ...... :(

Comment: You need a visitor in transit visa https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa since at Stansted you will likely pass through border control

Comment: "If you arrive at Stansted on an international flight you will need to pass through passport control/immigration, whether your connecting flight is domestic or international. You will therefore need the correct documentation for entry into Britain." http://www.stanstedairport.com/at-the-airport/airport-transfers/